# Why doesn't the signature of std::str::parse use a trait bound?

Tags: rust, traits

The signature of the `parse` method on the Rust's `str` primitive type is

```
pub fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err>
```

Why is it not as below?

```
pub fn parse<F: FromStr>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err>
```

I thought perhaps the primitive cast would ensure `Err` resolves to `FromStr::Err`, not `SomeOtherTrait::Err`.

Still, given the following line in the `parse` documentation...

> parse can parse any type that implements the FromStr trait

Why is there no trait bound?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does use a trait bound, however the bound is specified using the **where** clause. [Look closer](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse):

> ```
> pub fn parse<F>(&self) -> Result<F, <F as FromStr>::Err>
> where
>     F: FromStr,
> ```

Comment: So it does! It's obvious in the [source code view](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/str.rs.html#1797-1799), which is just what I was expecting to see.

Answer (score 0):

`<F as FromStr>::Err` means the associated `Err` type from `F`'s implementation of `FromStr`.

> Why is it not as below?
>
> ```
> pub fn parse<F: FromStr>(&self) -> Result<F, F::Err>
> ```

Because `F` could implement many different traits, all of which could have a different associated `Err` type. This syntax makes sure that it gets the type specifically associated with `F`'s `FromStr` implementation.